# Generate mongodb collection name postfix dynamically

Tags: mongodb

I have collection name with CollectionName name and want to copy all data into 'backup' collection name of which should be dynamically generated(db engine version is 4.0):

```
db.getCollection("CollectionName").aggregate([
{
    $out: {$concat: ["CollectionNameV2", "-", {$dateToString: { format: "%Y%m%dT%H%M%S", date: new Date(), timezone: "+0000" } } ] }
}
])
```

This gives error "$out stage requires a string argument, but found object' on server localhost:27017.". Documentation of $concat operation says it outputs string value. Can someone please help with this?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to format the date on the server (via `$dateToString`), I'm guessing this is not supported. Instead you could format the date on the client. You may need to experiment to find a working way to do this in MongoDB shell (which has a javascript runtime but not necessarily support of everything that a browser supports these days) and ultimately pass a string to `$out`.